# Why is it possible to use numeric string values to set integer fields in MySQL, and is this a feature that will always work?

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

I just noticed that phpMyAdmin for some reason always seems to use numeric string values instead of integer values (i.e. '5' instead of 5) in its generated SQL queries for writing data to integer fields in MySQL databases, which I did not know was even valid SQL.

This made me curious, so I did some follow-up experiments myself, and could confirm that this is indeed allowed, even in DDL queries like:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyIntField SET DEFAULT '5'
```

(where, possibly needless to say, the "MyIntField" is of the "int" type)

and also in normal insert and update queries like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyIntField) VALUES ('5');

UPDATE MyTable SET MyIntField = '5' WHERE id = 1;
```

How/why is this allowed by MySQL? Databases normally care about types, and strings and integers are definitely different types?

Also, with this "feature", the same SQL injection sanitation procedure could be used for both string values and integer values (instead of integer validation testing input values for integer fields and quote-escape-testing input values for string fields separately), so my follow-up question is: Can I depend on the existence and support of this feature under all conditions in MySQL, and also in future versions of MySQL, i.e. is it documented somewhere officially?

Comment: This is part of the normalization in mysql 5 (afaik). if the field is `int` it will allow a `string` but will parse the string as an int for you.

Comment: I don't get any applicable google hits pointing at any MySQL reference information for "mysql normalization", do you have any good link to such documentation, or perhaps a slightly altered term that will yield such hits?

Comment: As a matter of product management you can rely on it always working. The screams if they broke it would compel that, or the thought of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL is pretty lax about most things, by default fixing these errors by doing everything it can to not error out.

MySQL does have a strict mode though which would not allow that behaviour

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

For more info.

This 'feature' can also cause performance issues, comparing a sting to an index'ed int makes the index useless (in some cases, sometimes the optimiser can spot this and cast only the input)

> Strict SQL Mode
>
> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in
>   data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be
>   invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data
>   type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing
>   when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL
>   column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a
>   NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.) Strict mode
>   also affects DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Thanks! For future readers of this question, and since StackOverflow normally doesn't like links in answers without also including key-quotes from them, could you also possibly include the first paragraph from that link into your answer (i.e. the one containing _"For example, it might have the wrong data type for the column, or it might be out of range."_)?

Answer (score 3):

I would add, numeric strings is always *safer* than the opposite.

It will never lead to any critical problem if you use a numeric string to query a numeric field, i.e. `update table where number='1'` will work like a charm.

Whereas the opposite, if happens could be a disaster. If you compare a number with a string the latter is converted to a number. I.e. `update table where string=0` will likely update *all rows in the database* while a numeric string won't cause any harm: `update table where string='0'` will just leave all strings alone.